# Can't displaying ACF Wysiwyg Editor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

i'm trying to displaying ACF Wysiwyg Editor content to my page but it won't show. Can anyone help me please? here is my problem.

i put Wysiwyg Editor into this field group like this.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n99rP.png)

And this is my field rule. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZfdm.png)

and here is my code on index.php

```html
<div class="desc wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
        <?php if (have_rows('home_description', 'home_information')) : ?>
        <?php while (have_post('home_description')) : ?>
        <?php the_post('home_description'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p>Whoopssss no data yet, admin so lazy!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `<?php the_post('home_description'); ?>` is wrong. Use `<?php the_field('home_description'); ?>`. But I am 100% not clear about your question. You do not need any loop here. So, you can remove `if` and `while`.

Comment: sorry, i try to show the content inside the wysiwyg editor to my page but i can't. i alread change my code to

<div class="desc wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
       <?php the_field('home_description'); ?>
</div>

but still can't display the content

Comment: Is it a custom page or WordPress Options page.?

Comment: ah sorry, it's custom page

Comment: Check and fix the rule. Learn more at https://nerodev.com/how-to-use-advanced-custom-fields-in-wordpress/